# How to use 'sed' to automate changes of config file?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to create a script that dynamically finds line numbers in a .groovy config file and then utilizes the 'head/tail' command to insert multiple lines of code into the .groovy' config file. I cannot hardcode line numbers into the script because the vendor may alter the config and order of line numbers in the future. Anybody have suggestions for the best way to accomplish this?

EX.)

1: This is line one

2: This is line two

Problem: I need to insert:

```
test {
   test{
     authenticationProvider     =/random/path
   }
}
```

I cannot hard code the lie numbers in sed because they may change in the future. How can I dynamically make sed find the appropriate line number and insert multiple lines of code in the proper format?

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review your question and [edit] appropriately. Also, you mention dynamically, this generally implies that _you would like to perform a change if a given condition is satisfied_. We should know what this condition is. That is why we require an [mcve]. What is your input, what is your expected output? Also, it should be minimal. Furthermore, since we do not know what your input is and what you really want, this question is considered too broad. Please specify.

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
$ line_num=2; seq 5 | sed "${line_num}r insert"

1
2
test {
   test{
     authenticationProvider     =/random/path
   }
}
3
4
5
```

to be inserted text is placed in the file named `insert`.  Since there is no sample input file, I generated sequence of 5 as the input source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can find the line number, you could do this fairly easy with a bash script:

file `insert-lines.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYLINE=$1
FILE=$2
head -$MYLINE < $FILE
cat <<__END__
test {
  test{
    authenticationProvider     =/random/path
  }
}
__END__
tail +$((MYLINE+1)) $FILE
```

Then you can run this:

```
chmod 755 insert-lines.sh
./insert-lines.sh 3 .groovy > .groovy.new
mv .groovy.new .groovy
```

and the script will insert the block between lines 3 and 4 of the .groovy file.

Note that I'm assuming a recent Linux distro which supports the `tail +n` syntax, which outputs the end of the file starting at line *n*. You'll have to replace that part of the code if your version of `tail` does not support it.